# Invalid use of null Access-VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm getting an error when I use this button because of the if, give an error Invalid use of null, can someone explain?

```
Sub Concluído_Click()

    Dim novonome As String
    Dim dataadmi As Date
    Dim datanasc As Date
    Dim Email As Hyperlink
    Dim Cargo As String
    Dim Categoria As String
    Dim ingless As String
    Dim inglesw As String
    Dim coordeq As String
    Dim relcli As String
    Dim Java As String
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim PHP As String
    Dim wserv As String
    Dim Vendas As String
    Dim dgraf As String
    Set table = New ADODB.Recordset

    With Form_Funcionários


**If Len(.Nome.value & "") = 0 Or _
    ValornaColuna(.Nome.value, "Funcionários", "Nome") = True Then**
            MsgBox "Campo Nome do Formulario encontra-se vazio ou ja existe! Por favor altere o seu valor!", vbOKOnly, "Campo Vazio"
        End If
    End With


    HideAll

End Sub

Private Function ValornaColuna(ByVal value As String, ByVal formTable As String, ByVal formColumn As String) As Boolean

    Dim valueToCompare As String
    Dim C As Boolean
    Set table = New ADODB.Recordset

    table.Open formTable, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
    C = False

    While table.EOF = False And ExistsInColumn = False
        valueToCompare = table.Fields(formColumn)

        If StrComp(valueToCompare, value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            C = True
        End If
        table.MoveNext
    Wend

    table.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

This will throw an error (invalid use of Null) whenever `.Nome.value` is Null, because `ValornaColuna` requires String as the data type of its first parameter.  And Null is not String type.

```vb
If Len(.Nome.value & "") = 0 Or _
    ValornaColuna(.Nome.value, "Funcionários", "Nome") = True Then
```

You can avoid that error by using `Nz` to pass in an empty string whenever `.Nome.value` is Null.

```vb
If Len(.Nome.value & "") = 0 Or _
    ValornaColuna(Nz(.Nome.value, vbNullSting), "Funcionários", "Nome") = True Then
```

Comment: Thank you -- I had a similar situation where I had a routine declared as
`Public Function EmailField(Title, Value) As String`
 start throwing errors after I "improved" the parameter list to become 
`Public Function EmailField(Title As String, Value As String) As String`
.  My final answer was 
`Public Function EmailField(Title As String, Value) As String`
, and then deal with Value possibly being null within the routine